# Java: How to Unit Test an abstract class that consumes REST Services

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have two classes. The first `ServiceConsumer` is an abstract class that initializes the server settings in its constructor. It has protected methods that consume REST Services.

```
public abstract class ServiceConsumer {

public ServiceConsumer(String configFilePath) {
    initConfigSuccessful = false;
    initConfiguration(configFilePath);
}

protected RestResponse executeGetRequest(String urlString) {
    if (!initConfigSuccessful) {
        return RestResponseFactory.createErrorResponse("Initialization error!");
    }

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(urlString);
        byte[] authentication = Base64.getEncoder().encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
        getRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(authentication));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream responseStream = entity.getContent();
        String responseString = StringHelper.getFileContent(responseStream);
        JsonElement responseElement = new JsonParser().parse(responseString);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (responseElement == null || responseElement.isJsonNull()) {
            return RestResponseFactory.createResponse(responseCode);
        } else if (responseElement.isJsonObject()) {
            return RestResponseFactory.createResponse(responseCode, responseElement.getAsJsonObject());
        } else if (responseElement.isJsonArray()) {
            return RestResponseFactory.createResponse(responseCode, responseElement.getAsJsonArray());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return RestResponseFactory.createErrorResponse(e);
    }
    return RestResponseFactory.createErrorResponse("Unexpected error occured!");
    }
}
```

The second class `ServiceClient` extends the `ServiceConsumer` and calls the method super constructor and the methods.

```
public class ServiceClient extends ServiceConsumer {

private static String configFilePath = "/server-config.json";

public ServiceClient() {
    super(getConfigFilePath());
}

public RestResponse getStuffByKey(String key) {
    RestResponse restResponse = executeGetRequest(getBasicUrl() + "/rest/api/2/stuff/" + key);
    return restResponse;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to Unit Test this with Mockito. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what actions do you want to test?

Comment: The getStuffByKey and/or executeGetRequest methods.

Answer (score 2):

*Favor composition over inheritance* is the answer. `ServiceConsumer` is providing functionality to be invoked. But there is no reason for that functionality to be in a base class. Move this to it's own class, abstract that functionality with an interface and let `ServiceClient` depend on that interface.

Your code shows a clear warning sign of class design: Your derived class is calling a non-abstract protected method of the base class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand. Can you be a bit more specific what I have to do?